# Dojo - Set FilteringSelect's dropdown srcNodeRef

Tags: javascript, dojo

First post on SO, so please let me know if anything can be improved or is out of line.

I have a FilteringSelect inside a menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect"
        value="y"
        data-dojo-id="timeSelect"
        data-dojo-props="store:timeSelectStore, searchAttr:'name', required:false, placeHolder: 'Select a time'"
        name="time"
        id="timeSelector" 
    />
</div>
```

The menu closes if anything that isn't its child is clicked (i.e., if a click is registered outside of it):

```
// event listener added when menu is opened
on(document, "click", function (evt) {
    if (!dom.isDescendant(evt.target, dom.byId('menu'))) {
        closeMenu();
    }
});
```

This all works great, except for the dropdown widget created by the FilteringSelect. It gets appended to the `<body>`, rather than inserted after the FilteringSelect, so when the dropdown is clicked, the menu closes, as it is not a descendant of `<div id="menu">`. You can see a live version of this in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQKvp/3/).

Basically, I want the dropdown widget to be inserted right after the FilteringSelect, rather than at the end of the page. Now I'm assuming Dojo is doing a programmatic instantiation of the dropdown widget, so can I specify the srcNodeRef for that? If so, how? If not, is there a simpler way to move the widget's DOM node after it's been constructed?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no (non-hacky) way to auto place this as a sibling to the input. The filtering select should be handling the whole 'if you click outside of the filtering select the menu closes' thing for you though

Comment: That saved me a lot of time. I ended up doing a class-based workaround by doing `domClass.add(timeSelect.dropDown.domNode, 'menu_orphan');` the first time the widget is clicked and then checking it with `domClass.contains(evt.target.parentNode, 'menu_orphan')` in my menu event listener. Thanks for the answer.